# Java: Using executors to populate data

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have two codes where I am using ExecutorService of Java. 
I have some doubt about it's usages

- Is it a correct way ?
- Is it a good coding practice ?

  ```
              ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); try {
                  while (iter.hasNext()) {

                      final something = (something) iter.next();

                      Future<Data> fut = es
                              .submit(new Callable<Data>() {

                                  public Data call()
                                          throws Exception {
                                      return someMethod(param);
                                  }
                              });

                      listF.add(fut);
                  }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  // some exception
              } finally {
                  if (es != null && !es.isShutdown()) {
                      es.shutdown();
                      try {

                          es.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                      }
                  }
              }

              if (listF != null) {
                  dsInfo = new ArrayList<Data>();
                  for (Future<Data> df : listF) {
                      dsInfo.add(df.get());
                  }
              }
  ```

Please don't look for grammer and other normal coding errors.

I am not sharing any variables in the threads. No static instances. 
Every object is individual.

If this is not a good practice, what can be an alternative.

Here's is an operation,

There is a repetitive task, done in loop. Can I directly use ExecutorService to make it multithreaded to enhance the performance ?
If not, then any alternative ?

Comment: `There is a repetitive task`: is one loop affecting the next one somehow? Do they write to the same output? Is order important? You haven't answered any of these question to take an answer

Comment: Empty `catch` blocks are not good practice.

Comment: You shouldn't shut down the executer until after you've called `get` on those `Futures`